# Counting words per sentence and sentences per paragraph in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble obtaining normalising a dictionary. In my dictionary, I have a bunch of words we are meant to count in a text file. Now for each of these words/characters, "normalising", in the context of my project, is dividing their frequency/value by the total number of sentences in the given text. I then have to replace the old values of the dictionary with these new ones.

I.e. name of my dictionary is count, with keys and values like this:

```
{'and': 5, ';' : 3, '-' : 0...}
```

```
def main(textfile, normalize == True):
    .
    .
    .
    .
    if normalize == True:
        for x in count:
            new_count[x] = count[x]/numSentence
            print(x,count[x])
```

Here's a sample file to try any codes on: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xph5pb9bdf551h/sample2.txt?dl=0
Also note in the above code the normalise == True is there because in the top-level function

Comment: So great - you got a task. What is your problem? Please create a [mcve] that reflects that so we can execute and see for ourself.

Comment: I don't really know how I can create a whole example out of this. I'm assuming it's just a small edit that's required? All I need to do is divide each value of each key in the dictionary by a number and then print the new dictionary. But I don't know where the code is wrong.

Comment: The code looks about right, assuming you've instantiated `new_count = {}` and found the number of sentences. "_I'm having trouble_" is rather vague—which part is troublesome? Is it raising an error or exhibiting incorrect logical behaviour? Please elaborate. (Also, the function parameter should be `normalize=True`.)